# In C#, how to merge .png files into one single.png file

Tags: c#, .net

I am capturing screen shot of the webpage. And then save it in one .png file and merge this file into one final .png file.
I can save first .png file into final .png file but for second .png files and onwards they are not merging ...

here is my code. The else block is not working :(
lastappend is integer which increases for every screenshot program takes. Initially its 1

```
 ********************************* Code *************
string fileName = "Funds";
Bitmap bmpScreenshot;
         Graphics gfxScreenshot;

              bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

                   gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

                   gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

bmpScreenshot.Save("C:\\Test\\Images\\Temp\\Image" +lastAppend+ ".Png", ImageFormat.Png); 

   Image img1 = Image.FromFile(Constants.testImagePath + "Image" + lastAppend + ".Png");

   string mergedScreenShot = (Constants.testImagePath + fileName + ".Png"); // Here constants.testimagepath is C:\\Test\\Images\\Temp\\Image

       if (lastAppend == 1)
       {

           bmpScreenshot.Save(Constants.testImagePath + fileName + ".Png");

          img1.Dispose();

       }

       else
       {

           Image mergeimg = Image.FromFile(mergedScreenShot);

                  int  width = mergeimg.Width;
           int height = mergeimg.Height;
        Bitmap img3 = new Bitmap(width, height);       // setting bitmap object of the merged file
           Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img3);           
           g.DrawImage(img1, new Point(width, height));
           g.Save();

           img3.Save(mergedScreenShot);
           img1.Dispose();
           g.Dispose();
           img3.Dispose();

       }

 *********** End of code ***************
```

Comment: What is it doing vs. what are you expecting it to do? Are you getting an error? Does it crash? etc. Basically saying "it doesn't work" isn't helpful since I don't even know what you mean by "merge"

Comment: I have made one final file where I copy all the screen shots one after another .       With merge I mean copying the current .png file next to the previous one in the final file  ..                    In the else block the code do not copy  the current .png file into the final file...

Comment: On top of each other in layers? Or are you intending to arrange them horizontally or vertically and the image size should grow to accomodate? I don't know what merge means. If you're simply writing it "over" the original (which is what your code looks like), a screenshot doesn't have transparency typically so you wouldn't see more than one image. I still don't know what you mean.

Comment: I am trying to add .png files one after another horizontally...

Comment: Well then you shouldn't be initializing the new merged image to the same width and height as the original. You need to increase the width based on the combined width. Also, you don't want to draw at point `width,height` but rather `width,0` otherwise you're putting it diagonally below the original.

Comment: can you also check and let me know if I have put dispose correctly. I think it can be because of the dispose methods that my program is not copying the image ..

Comment: Dispose would have no affect on that unless you're getting some kind of exceptions, which you did not indicate. The best way to handle disposing though is with `using` blocks which I'd strongly recommend you use.

Comment: I have changed the code, can you please see why I am getting this error now

Comment: There are a number of libraries to do this sort of thing - the most popular is ImageMagick, but there are others.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the solution is found by using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). There's been some work to have .NET wrappers https://magick.codeplex.com/

The other option would be for you to just invoke the ImageMagick executibles on the server for you:

1. Write images to disk
2. Use [Process.Start()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process) to execute the program with relevant flags
3. Scoop up processed image to be returned or whatever